# Get count of items that have a value in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an Array like so:

```
search_results = [{policy: {isActive: true}}]
```

And I want to get the count of `search_result`s where `isActive` is true. In this case, the Array only contains 1 item whose `policy` `isActive` object is `true`.

I tried with:

```
search_results.group_by { |x| x.policy.isActive }.count
```

However I always get `1` back. Regardless if `isActive` is true or false.

Comment: _"I always get 1 back"_ – that's unusual, it should raise a `NoMethodError` because `Hash` doesn't respond to `policy`.

Comment: @Stefan `search_results.count { |sr| sr.policy.isActive }` worked for me. I'm using RubyMine and also new to Ruby, so I took a guess at how the search_results displayed in Evaluate Expression would look as just code to show on here. If it's not a hash and that syntax worked... what is it?

Comment: `search_results.first.class` should reveal its actual class.

Comment: @Stefan Gives me `result = {class} SearchResult`.

Comment: Seems like you have a custom class `SearchResult`, not a plain `Hash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access hash key-value pair with `[]`, not `.`.

```
search_results.count { |hash| hash[:policy][:isActive] }
```

If you're using newer Ruby version, you can make use of [Hash#`dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) (Ruby 2.3+) and [Enumerable#`sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) (Ruby 2.4+):

```
search_results.sum { |hash| hash.dig(:policy, :isActive) }
```